# How to get Swashbuckle working on sitefinity 10.x

Tags: swagger, sitefinity, swashbuckle

I had installed Swashbuckle on Sitefinity 7.x and it was working just fine, after update my Sitefinity project to 10.x it stopped working (getting 500 error).  I have tried different version of Swashbuckle with the same setup without success, I have also tried some different Swashbuckle configuration without much luck.

This is the setup code I have in the Sitefinity project's Global.asax (which used to work)

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bootstrapper.Initialized += Bootstrapper_Initialized;
    }

    private void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, ExecutedEventArgs args)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("ipad");

        if (args.CommandName == "RegisterRoutes")
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            CustomPageRouteHandler.RegisterType();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new LoggingFilterAttribute());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionInvoker), new ControllerActionInvoker());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilterAttribute());

            JsonDefaultSerializer.ConfigureApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "xxx.Web");
                    c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerCustomControllersFilter>();
                    c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
                    c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
                })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                    c.DisableValidator();
                });

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
        }
    }
```

The following is the error message I am getting:

> {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
>       "StackTrace": " at System.Collections.Generic.DictionaryExtensions.TryGetValue[T](IDictionary`2 collection, String key, T& value)
>       at System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.ExploreRouteControllers(IDictionary`2 controllerMappings, IHttpRoute route)
>       at System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.InitializeApiDescriptions()
>       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>       at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String rootUrl, String apiVersion)
>       at Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__0.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()"
>   }

here are some of the packages versions:
Swashbuckle 5.6.0
Swashbuckle.Core 5.6.0
System.Net.Http 4.3.3
WebActivatorEx 2.2.0

Comment: Do you have minimal project somewhere reproducing this issue? I would like to try with Swagger-Net see if the error is there too...

Comment: @HelderSepu unfortunately with sitefinity I can't share the project because of license issues.

Comment: You don't have to share that exact project... Can you create a minimal one reproducing the issue? Maybe host it in Nuget and share a link here.

Comment: @JonathasSucupira did you ever get this working? To me it looks like I want to try and ignore Sitefinity API controllers or something?

Comment: @Technicolour I haven't gotten this working yet. I stopped working on it for now.  Currently I already have a filter that ignores Sitefinity API's, that piece of code hasn't changed.

Comment: @Technicolour I started working on this again, and it seems that something is breaking System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.  Now the ApiDescriptions are null and this is what is throwing the exception.

Comment: @JonathasSucupira I found the same thing, narrowed it down to a particular route. I then lodged a ticket with Progress and it should be getting fixed with the next internal build of Sitefinity :)

Comment: @Technicolour cool, thank you for the update.